# xcode svn missing frameworks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I just downloaded an Xcode project and all the frameworks are missing.  It wouldn't be such a big deal except that somehow when I right click -> add existing frameworks they aren't their and they should be.

To name a few: MapKit.framework, MediaPlayer.framework
OpenGLS.framework,CFNetwork.framework, CoreGraphics.framework, CoreLocation.framework CoreMotion.framework

I've seen them there before... I thought.... where have they gone?  Why did they show up in the project if they didn't actually come down with the full svn checkout?

Just to reiterate, when I right click -> add existing frameworks most frameworks are listed, but not the ones above, even when I have all selected in the drop down at the top.

Thank you for any help.  I'm using Xcode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied all the frameworks from

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework

to

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework

and that fixed it.